# Azure Table REST API / 403 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Works in Postman but not on static web page

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-static-web-app

I have an azure static web page setup and want to communicate with my Azure Table service through REST API, which I was told would be possible.

This is what my fetch code block looks like:

```
     fetch('https://storagename.table.core.windows.net/Tables', {
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: {
            'Accept': '*/*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*',
            'Authorization': `SharedKey storagename:${sigBase64}`,
            'Date': date.toUTCString(),
            'x-ms-version': '2019-02-02',
            'DataServiceVersion': '3.0;NetFx',
        },
        redirect: 'follow'
    }).then(function(response){
        if (response.ok){
            return response.json();
        }else{
            return Promise.reject(response);
        }
    }).then(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    })
```

On my Azure Table settings under Resources, I've enabled CORS for all domains (*).

I'm a little confused as to what troubleshooting I can try next. I'm assuming there is some CORS policy or header I'm missing but the 403 return message doesn't help too much.

Does anyone have an idea of what I should look into next?

After a while I figured out how to properly authorize my requests through the Shared Key signature. I validated this by using Postman and sending a simple GET request with the correct Date/Authorization headers, and get a 200 response.

[My CORS Settings in Azure:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYbxs.png)

Comment: Please edit your question and include your complete CORS settings if you are still facing issues.

Comment: @GauravMantri do you mean the CORS settings in Azure? I believe under Table, it should allow all domains. I have '*' entered in the allowed domains. I've updated my post with a photo.